# ftp_put(): Opening ASCII mode data connection

Tags: php, ftp

I have a script that takes an sql backup every day and store it to my server (about 20MB). After that I want to send  the file to my office NAS but I am getting error "ftp_put(): Opening ASCII mode data connection". Actualy is and an 500 Internal Server Error and at the error log I am getting "ftp_put(): Opening ASCII mode data connection for bn_170930011208.sql"

The file though is getting transferred to the NAS but not entirely.

I tried also changing mode to BINARY but still getting the error.

Any suggestions?

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes

$file = "/home/USER/public_html/_backup/bn_170930011208.sql";

$conn_id = ftp_connect('MY_DYNDNS_OFFICE_NAS_ADDRESS') or die("Can't connect");
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, "USER", "PASS")or die("Can't login");
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

ftp_set_option($conn_id, FTP_TIMEOUT_SEC, 300);


 // change the directory 
if (ftp_chdir($conn_id, "web/bn/")) {
    echo "Current directory is now: " . ftp_pwd($conn_id) . "\n";
} else { 
    echo "Couldn't change directory\n";
} 
// upload file
if (ftp_put($conn_id, "bn_170930011208.sql", $file, FTP_ASCII))
  {
  echo "Successfully uploaded $file.";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error uploading $file.";
  }
// close connection
ftp_close($conn_id); 
?>
```

Comment: That's not an error, it's just an informative message.

Comment: @Barmar I edit the question. A 500 error will prevent me to continue with redirects and/or other tasks like deleting the original file

Comment: I'm pretty sure that message is a warning, not an error.

Comment: What does the `ftp_put` return? How long does the upload take before it fails?

Comment: @Martin Prikryl The script runs for about 40sec. Running some tests, up to 14mb - 30sec, everything works fine! I am wondering if has to do with php.ini but is set to 240sec

Comment: Can you FTP any file from the same machine that runs your PHP code to the NAT using any standalone FTP client?